# What is a good architecture to store user files if using Mongo schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Simply, I need to build an app to store images for users. So each user can upload images and view them on the app.
I am using NodeJS and Mongo/Mongoose.

Is this a good approach to handle this case:

1. When the user uploads the image file, I will store it locally.
2. I will use Multer to store the file.
3. Each user will have a separate folder created by his username.
4. In the user schema, I will define a string array that records the file path.
5. When user needs to retrieve the file, I will check the file path, retrieve it from the local disk.

Now my questions are:

- Is this a good approach (storing in local file system and storing path in schema?
- Is there any reason to use GridFS, if the file sizes are small (<1MB)?
- If I am planning to use S3 to store files later, is this a good strategy?

This is my first time with a DB application like this so very much appreciate some guidance.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, storing the location within your database for use within your application and the physical file elsewhere is an appropriate solution.  Depending on the data store and number of files it can be detrimental to store within a database as it can impede processes like backup and replication if there are many large files

2) I admit that I don't know GridFS but the documentation says it is for files larger than 16MB so it sounds like you don't need it yet

3) S3 is a fantastic product and enables edge caching and backup through services and many others too.  I think your choice needs to look at what AWS provides and if you need it e.g. global caching or replication to different countries and data centres.  Different features cause different price points but personally I find the S3 platform excellent and have around 500G loaded there for different purposes.